# Can item despawn rate be changed in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I'm running a minecraft 1.8.8 server using craftbukkit. I've read about a config option to change the item despawn rate after death. how is this done if possible or is there a plugin that i can download?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do it with a plugin but it is possible with command blocks.

Basic concept: Set the age to the desired amount for newly dropped items

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add newItem dummy
```

Loop:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,score_newItem_min=!1] {Age:<Despawn Rate>}
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] dummy 1
```

Replace `<Despawn Rate>` with `6000 - Life length of item in terms of ticks`.

Answer (score 0):

[Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/), which is effectively a follower for CraftBukkit and compatible with the same plugins (and more of its own), [has item-despawn-rate configuration option](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-configuration/).

Comment: As a side-note, [Paper](https://paper.readthedocs.io/en/paper-1.11/) (AKA PaperSpigot) is a high-performance fork of Spigot with more performance-oriented configuration options.